# Choosing a hash function for API call to determine when to update

Tags: api, optimization, hash, query-optimization, checksum

**Context:** 
In the design of our application, for certain frequently-used APIs, the response will be big (~3-5MB). For example, an API call to get all the profiles of 1000 users. 
Moreover, more often than not, the response will stay relatively the same - unchanged. We want to save the information in the front-end store (e.g., redux-store) as a JSON object, and when the FE calls the BE to retrieve the information, we will pass in a calculated checksum as a hash value of the JSON object - let say using MD5 function. BE will calculate the response in hash value using MD5 as well. And BE will only return the response if the hash values are different. Otherwise, it will return something like `HTTP.status.OK` 
*I wonder what the most appropriate hash function for this type of operation would be, what are the criteria to choose one*? Seem like no global answer from what I searched. Indeed, it should be fast, but I feel like the time to calculate a hash value is ignorable compared to other database operations. Also, the chance of collisions is negligible as well.

Comment: The costs for calculating a hash are in fact negligible. I propose, that you use sha256 - the chance of a collision is practically zero. (The amount of possible hash values is similar to the likely amount of atoms in the whole universe).

Comment: The BE will still need to fetch the data from the database and serialize it etc before it can decide on returning just OK or send over the new blob. Also, keep in mind that 'insignificant differences' may cause the hash to return a different value. E.g. if the JSON contains John, Eva and Frank it will be equivalent to the new one containing Eva, Frank and John but the hash will be different; so make sure that e.g. the order of the elements is explicit. (There may be other culprits)

Comment: Intel and AMD processors have hardware instructions to speed up SHA-1 and SHA-256 computation so it can be computed much more efficiently than other hash assuming the target library use them (web libraries tends to be inefficiently implemented and often do not pay attention to hardware capabilities though...). AFAIK, this should not speed up variants like SHA-224. SHA hashes are known to be relatively well balanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any hash function with a low collision probability is workable for this application. You're not using the hash to secure your data against modification.

That being said, you should avoid MD5 for code-reviewer and boss reasons. It's no longer good for security, and some people don't like seeing it used in any new code.

SHA2-224 should be fine, for performance, security, and boss satisfaction.